# Android :add spinner and editText dynamically raising an exception

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm trying to add dinamically spinner and two editText , but i'm having an exception . Well i suspect this line of code :
 `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.id.simple_spinner_item,items);`

Because when i tryed to display an empty spinner and two editTexts ,it worked perfectly, but when added values to the spinner ,it crashed. I think the problem is comming from :

`R.id.simple_spinner_item` ,i added the simple simple_spinner_item in xml file.

This my java code :

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SSIDZone);
             String[] items = new String[]{  "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"};  

                for (int i =0;i<number;i++)
                { LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
                l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                Spinner spin = new Spinner(this);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.id.simple_spinner_item,items);//suspected line
                LayoutParams lp3 = new LayoutParams();
                l.addView(spin,lp3);
                spin.setAdapter(adapter);


                EditText text1 = new EditText(this);
                LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams();
                l.addView(text1,lp1);

                EditText text2 = new EditText(this);
                LayoutParams lp2 = new LayoutParams();
                l.addView(text2,lp2);


                linearLayout.addView(l);
                }
```

And this my xml layout :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SSIDZone"
            android:layout_width="312dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.46"
            android:background="#30ad9e"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/simple_spinner_item"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

And finaly this is my LogCat :

```
    05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050053 type #0x12 is not valid
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2184)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:872)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:193)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:439)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1059)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1220)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:321)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:850)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2200)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-27 15:36:25.989: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oups stupid question !! I didn't get enoght attention .This a working code, in case someone will need it.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SSIDZone);
         String[] items = new String[]{  "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"};  

            for (int i =0;i<number;i++)
            { LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
            l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            Spinner spin = new Spinner(this);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,items);//suspected line
            LayoutParams lp3 = new LayoutParams();
            l.addView(spin,lp3);
            spin.setAdapter(adapter);


            EditText text1 = new EditText(this);
            LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams();
            l.addView(text1,lp1);

            EditText text2 = new EditText(this);
            LayoutParams lp2 = new LayoutParams();
            l.addView(text2,lp2);


            linearLayout.addView(l);
            }
```

And this is the xml file :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SSIDZone"
            android:layout_width="312dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.46"
            android:background="#30ad9e"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes i found it by my self. I can accept it after two days. @DerGolem

Comment: So much? I thought it was 15 minutes. Anyway, bravo, for finding the answer.